# EmberJS RC8: how to notify parent model when children got updated?

Tags: ember.js

The new RC8 breaks my app (my fault though...) due to this change:

> [UNCONSUMED COMPUTED PROPERTIES DO NOT TRIGGER OBSERVERS](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html)

Indeed, I have the following scenario:

```
Children belongTo Parent belongsTo GrandParent
```

and I needed GrandParent to be notified when a descendent was updated. So at each model level I had a computed property like this:

```
// In GrandParent
innerChange: Ember.computed(function(){
}).property('parents.@each.innerChange'),

// In Parent
innerChange: Ember.computed(function(){
}).property('children.@each.innerChange'),
```

I know it is bad and not idiomatic so I was hoping to change this instead of fixing it.

EDIT: by "fixing it" I meant using the init hook and getting the property (cf intuitivepixel answer). But I think RC8 breaking this shows that what I am doing is not idiomatic. So I was hoping to do it differently.

Is there a proper way to do that now in Ember? Or does it have to be done manually, still?

Answer (score 0):

Stating the [new blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html) about the rc8 relase might helps you, important phrase at the bottom in **bold**:

> UNCONSUMED COMPUTED PROPERTIES DO NOT TRIGGER OBSERVERS
>   If you never get a computed property, its observers will not fire even if its dependent keys change. You can think of the value changing from one unknown value to another.
>   This doesn't usually affect application code because computed properties are almost always observed at the same time as they are fetched. For example, you get the value of a computed property, put it in DOM (or draw it with D3), and then observe it so you can update the DOM once the property changes.

**If you need to observe a computed property but aren't currently retrieving it, just get it in your init method.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know about that, I should have mentioned it. My question really was: clearly the way I am doing this is not good. That's all I could think of and it used to work. But RC8 - I think - clearly shows that what I am doing is not right. There's got to be a proper way now...

Comment: @PJC, I don't think you are doing it wrong, simply that the behaviour has changed. And the only thing you might be doing wrong as by now is that you are never `get()`ting your CP in your code, and the last line in the paragraph is stating how to go about this to make it work again, hope it makes sense?